# Delete group by its creator Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

quick question

I have an app, where users can create groups for their friends, after adding some, I would like to keep functions such as `delete` or `update` only to the user, who created the group. Can anybody may help? My solution so far is hardcoded, if I add a specific id of a person, only this user can delete the group, but I'd like to have more universal solution.

views.py

```
class TripDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Trip
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'tripplanner/delete_trip_confirm.html'

    def test_func(self):
        detailView = self.get_object()
        # Correct, not hardcode
        if self.request.user == detailView.profile.get(pk=2):
            return True
        return False
```

models.py

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    ...
    profile = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='profile_groups')

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Comment: can you show the model structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as it was expected is very simple, I've just added another field in my `Trip` model, which is `owner` thanks to that, I have only one profile, which will get required permissions. Below some code:

models.py

```
class Trip(models.Model):

    owner = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='profile_owners')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='profile_members')
```

views.py

```
class TripDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Trip
    ...

    def test_func(self):
        detailView = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user in detailView.owner.all():
            return True
        return False
```